# Limit what fields are indexed on library search results

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a document library with several thousand training documents loaded.  Each document has a corresponding `"Employee"` field.

When I use the search box `"Find a File"` in the library web part, the automatic indexing works well.

However, I uploaded all the documents, and so if I try to search for my documents, all results are returned.  I am not sure if it is crawling the `"Created By"` or `"Modified By"` fields but can I remove those from the search?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the Indexing or excluding the Created By and Modified by fields from Search. I don't think, you can do it on Library Level but there are some settings which will apply to everybody.

Go to `Central Admin > Search Service Application > search setting -> metadata property mapping`. check the Created By and Modified By Properties and Uncheck this “Include values from all crawled properties mapped” for both properties.
Now Run Full Crawl.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add "Employee" field as a managed field in your search service application, rather than delete "Created by" or "Modified by". Deleting them would most likely create more problems for you than solve any.

Try to add " Employee" as a managed field and then try to create a refiner based on that in your search center. It should be quite simple. Good luck!